# Accessing project files from vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

Opening the command terminal from Google Cloud Platform you're greeted with a project level shell

```
account_name@cloudshell:/ (project_name)$
```

after starting up a new VM it's possible to send files from the project level file system to the VM like so:

```
account_name@cloudshell:/ (project_name)$ gcloud compute scp --recurse \
> ~/project-file vm-name:~
```

after ssh-ing into the new VM how do you perform the same file transfer from inside the VM?

Everything I've tried ends up looking like this:

```
account_name@vm-name:~$ gcloud compute scp --recurse \
> cloudshell:~/project-file ~
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/project_name/zones/my_zone/instances/cloudshell' was not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gcloud compute scp` command does not support Google Cloud Shell as source/target.

Google has recently added new commands to the "alpha" version of `gcloud` which support Cloud Shell.

`gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:~/REMOTE-DIR localhost:~/LOCAL-DIR`

The problem using this command inside a VM instance is that VMs use Service Account credentials. Cloud Shell is assigned/created on a per-user credential basis. There is a different Cloud Shell instance for each User ID - created on the fly. With a service account, you cannot identify to Cloud Shell which instance you want to interact with. This means a new Cloud Shell instance is created not mapped to a user identity.

Note: It looks like the API might support this in the future, but the current implementation does not have a method to specify either the user name or OAuth credentials.

You need to use User Credentials (OAuth 2.0) to communicate with Cloud Shell. Unless you have a GUI desktop to run a web browser inside your VM instance, you cannot create User Credentials suitable for Google Cloud Shell authentication.

You can either limit yourself to copying files to/from the VM instance using commands in the Cloud Shell instance or look at a program that I just released that implements a CLI for Cloud Shell. If you chose the second method, authenticate to Cloud Shell from your desktop and then copy the user_credentials.json file with my program to your VM instance. Then you have a fairly powerful command line tool for Cloud Shell interaction.

[Google Cloud Shell CLI](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-shell-cli-in-go/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already have a large learning curve using GCS so checking out your program is a hard sell. I think I'll just try to work around my problem for now.

Comment: No problem. In my post, I gave you the answer.